# Is it possible to make a background task with node socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io in order to push notification to browsers.
Those notifications are triggered by action from other browsers.
I want to make a background task which send notification sometimes.
For example, at 12:45:21 i want to fire a notification to all connected users, even if they are doing nothing. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: there are two answers in front of you. and you have still not responded, whether any of them are working /nor working.... thats bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, and it's easy. Just use the standard Javascript setInterval technique:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

setInterval(function() {
    io.emit('hi!');
}, 60000);
```

This will send a message to all connected clients every 60 seconds. To achieve specific-time sending, just alter the method above so it's called every 1 second, and inside it, compare the current time to the time you want to trigger at.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should be possible. Stay connected with me, luckily we just started investing that almost same situation. and my gut feeling say to do this.

you must have a open connection from all the browser active. this is possible by opeing socket from default.jade which will be effective in all page.

```
//client side code effective in all pages.
socket = io(); 
socket.emit('join');
```

now on server side  store them into a default room.

```
 socket.on('join', function(json){
      socket.join('globalroom');
   });
```

thus you will be able to emit to that room, at 12:45.

```
 io.to('globalroom').emit('msg', "Happy new Year. ");
```